# Xcode 14 new project with storyboards

Tags: ios, swiftui, storyboard, xcode14, uiscenedelegate

When I start a new project with Xcode 14, I'm unable to change the interface from SwiftUI to storyboards.

Where can I create a new project, that uses storyboards instead of SwiftUI?

Comment: Just use the drop downs when you are creating a new project. You will find storyboards option

Comment: Could you please paste Xcode 14 screen shots? I just can't find it nowhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click on iOS
[image]

Then use the drop down
[image]

Comment: In Xcode 14, if you don't see the "Interface:" option on the dialog shown in the screenshot above...make sure that when you create your new project, Xcode was totally closed. When you have an already open Xcode project, close it and then close Xcode.